# How can I replace \xA0 (or Non-ASCII) chars in a string to ' '?

Tags: delphi, string, non-ascii-characters

I have an excel file with numerous Non-ASCII characters which I would like to replace with the space character.

This text is to be entered into a MySQL database, and it will not import with these characters in the strings. I get a `HY000 Incorrect string value` when trying to post the row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the set of Non-Ascii characters is fixed you could use:

```
NewString := StringReplace(OriginalString,#1#4,' ',[rfReplaceAll])
```

where #1#4 is the non-ascii characters you want to have replaced.

[Here is some docs on it's use.](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=StringReplace)

You could also do this.

```
function StripNonAlpha(aInput : String) : String;
var
 I : Integer;
begin
 result := aInput;
 for I := 1 to length(result) do
 begin
   if not CharInSet(result[I],['A'..'Z','a'..'z']) then
      result[I] := ' ';
 end;
end;
```

Then you can change Set in CharInSet to the acceptable characters.

Comment: Thanks Rob, worked well. For Delphi 7 function StripNonAlpha(aInput : String) : String;
var
 I : Integer; 
begin 
 result := aInput; 
 for I := 1 to length(result) do 
 begin 
   if not (result[I] in ValidChars) then
      result[I] := ' ';
 end; 
end; Where ValidChars: Set of Char = ['0'..'9','A'..'Z','a'..'z','?','.','>','<','+','-','~','!','@','#','$','%','&','*','(',')','_','=','{','}','[',']','|','\','/',':',';',' '];